# Как сравнить переменную с выводом print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу разобраться, хотелось бы небольшой пример. Есть две переменные

```
a = 'Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC... found'
b = 'Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC... not found'
```

И есть вывод print

```
Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC... found!MAC has IP 99.99.99.99
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Каким образом можно сравнить эти две переменные с выводом print?

Comment: А как print  выводится?

Comment: @nick_gabpe `print(data)`

Comment: Ну например проверить наличие текста в вашем "print-е", что бы это не значило, оператором `in`

Comment: @sakhalin совсем непонятно про какой вывод вы говорите и как вы его получаете.  советую ознакомитса с механикой тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030601/substring-search-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
output = io.StringIO()
print(data, file=output)
```

сравниваем `a` и  `output.getvalue()`

Comment: `data` можно напрямую с `a` сравнить: `a in data`.

Comment: @jfs a in data это не сравнение а поиск подстроки в строке

Comment: @Reishin поиск включает в себя и сравнение содержимого. Посмотрите на пример data в вопросе, сравнение вида `a == data` всегда ложно будет.

Comment: @Reishin А если логически подумать то каким образом оператор `in` ищет подстроку в строке ??? Думаю как раз через сравнение

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч думаю вам надо почитать документацию https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

Comment: @Reishin и что там опровергает мои слова ? Исходники смотрите.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч подскажите различие между словами "содержит" и "одинаковый", если ничего противоречещаго не видите.

Comment: @Reishin а при чем здесь эти два слова, если сам алгоритм поиска строки в подстроке (в двух словах) через сравнение по смещению построен. Что то вас не понимаю. Если интересует полная реализация смотрите исходники cpython. Вы на черное говорите белое.